# BeautifulSoup doesn't catch the complete link

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I try to get the link on a web page, `bs4` doesn't catch the entire link, it stops before the `**?ref**....`.
I'll explain the question through the code:

```
imdb_link = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250"
site = requests.get(imdb_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.text,'lxml')

for items in soup.find("table",class_="chart").find_all(class_="titleColumn"):
    link = items.find("a").get('href')
    print(link)
```

The output is:

```
/title/tt0111161/
/title/tt0068646/
/title/tt0071562/
/title/tt0468569/
/title/tt0050083/
/title/tt0108052/
/title/tt0167260/
...and so on..
```

But it's wrong, as you can see by seeing the web page, because it might be:

```
/title/tt0111161/?ref_=adv_li_tt
/title/tt0068646/?ref_=adv_li_tt
...and so on...
```

How can I get the entire link? I mean the **`?ref_=adv_li_tt`** too?

I use Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall it might be interesting to try and work out how to get the full link - which I think you will need selenium for to allow javascript to run on page, you don't need the full link as seen on rendered page. What you have, with addition of prefix `https://www.imdb.com`, is perfectly serviceable.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_25')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    links = ['https://www.imdb.com' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('.titleColumn a')]

    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        print(soup.select_one('title').text)
```

You could let selenium load page so content renders then pass over to bs4 to get links as on page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_25')
soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
d.quit()
links = ['https://www.imdb.com' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('.titleColumn a')]
```

Comment: Thank you! Infact I have used Selenium for that, but now I realize, thanks to you, that for my scope I need only a prefix.